# How to use linkit package after uplaoding file with filedepot package?

Tags: navigation, files

I am using [File Depot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) to upload files.

What I want to do is to upload some images into the filedepot folders and then make a link to that files in my posts/pages/book pages/etc. Is it possible ?

What would be even better is to be able to find the files using [LinkIt](http://drupal.org/project/linkit). Is that possible ?

Comment: What did you try to do?  If you ran into a problem, please post the specific steps you took.  If you want to know how to do something, be very specific about what you want to do.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I just update my question

Answer (score 0):

this is an older thread, but maybe [Linkit Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit_upload) is a nice solution for this problem.
With that module enabled you can upload files directly from the Linkit popup.